# Can two different TypeScript interfaces be required to have the same keys but be able to have different values?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I want to be able to enforce that objValidator has the same keys as the obj that it validates. Is this possible in TypeScript? Any ideas on how I can implement something like this below? Mainly the obj and objValidator must have the same keys, but the key values are different.

I would like to be able to be warned if my objValidator does not have the exact same keys as the obj.

```
interface obj {
  alpha: number
  beta: string
}

interface objValidator {
  alpha: {
    message: string
    valid(ALPHA'S TYPE): boolean
  }
  beta: {
    message: string
    valid(BETA'S TYPE): boolean
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) maybe:

```
interface Obj {
  alpha: number
  beta: string
}

type Validator<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: {message: string, valid: boolean};
};

let o: Obj = { alpha: 1, beta: "123" };
let v: Validator<Obj> =
{
  alpha: {
    message: "ok",
    valid: true
  },
  beta: {
    message: "not ok",
    valid: false
  }
}
```

Comment: By changing `valid: boolean` to `valid: (t: T[P]) => boolean` you can have the custom behavior for checking the key as well @JoeyFarina

Comment: This code can be compared to black magic. It's amazing!

Comment: you didn't create two interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need... im no ts master.. butd the only thing I can think of:

```
interface IBase<a=any, b=any> {
  alpha: a,
  beta: b,
}
export interface Interface1 extends IBase<string, number> {}
export interface Interface2 extends IBase<
  { message: string, valid: Interface1['alpha'] },
  { message: string, valid: Interface1['beta'] }
> {}

// so then...
const test1: Interface1 = { alpha: 'hello2', beta: 123 };
const test2: Interface2 = { 
  alpha: { message:'msg', valid: 'true' },
  beta: { message:'msg', valid: 123 },
};
```

Note: i think you'd have to have the `allow empty interfaces` setting turned on in the tsconfig.